# How we ensure that

Tags: sql-server, csv, etl

Import flat file into database table by using SQL server 2014 and now need to validate that all data of file is exist in tables or not. It is the term of test process when we need to validate that all record is successfully in tables and we have no column by which we ensure data and number or columns are equal in both side but number of rows are different SQL table have more data.

Comment: You can use insert with update or you can check [this](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically check the count of rows on both source, i.e. csv file and destination, i.e. sql server table. For this you need to read data from both of them as Source and then put it to a Row Count Transformation and assign them to SSIS variables and then compare the variables value and based on that perform required action like sending some emails, writing to a table, etc.

Row Count Transformation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/row-count-transformation?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: but number of rows are different and i also want to validate data means values of columns for respective row.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table and copy your flat files there and then compare that temp table with destination table.

Comment: But how we identify  which row of temp table  is matched by which row of destination table.

Comment: okay, so you need to modify your csv file, append a new value in each row of csv file and take unique value and treat that column like primary key and after that import your file to database table and after that you have a primary key(unique value) column in both source and destination then you validate the data.